# Python, regex to filter elements endswith a style in a list

Tags: python, regex

With regex, I want to find out which of the elements in a list, endswith the style (yyyy-mm-dd), for example (2016-05-04) etc.

The pattern r'(2016-\d\d-\d\d)' looks alright even tough naive. What's the right way to combine it with Endswith?

Thank you.

```
import re

a_list = ["Peter arrived on (2016-05-04)", "Building 4 floor (2020)", "Fox movie (2016-04-04)", "David 2016-08-", "Mary comes late(true)"]

style = r'\(2016\-\d\d\-\d\d\)'

for a in a_list:
    if a.endswith(style):
        print a
```

Comment: `style = r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine regex with string operations. Just use `re.search` to find match and use the anchor `$` in your pattern to check if the match happens at the end

```
>>> import re
>>> style = re.compile(r'\(2016-\d\d-\d\d\)$')
>>> for a in a_list:
...     if style.search(a):
...         print (a)
... 
Peter arrived on (2016-05-04)
Fox movie (2016-04-04)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `r'\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\)$'`

**Ex:**

```
import re

a_list = ["Peter arrived on (2016-05-04)", "Building 4 floor (2020)", "Fox movie (2016-04-04)", "David 2016-08-", "Mary comes late(true)"]

style = r'\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\)$'

for a in a_list:
    if re.search(style, a):
        print a
```

**Output:**

```
Peter arrived on (2016-05-04)
Fox movie (2016-04-04)
```

Comment: thank you for the help! Would you mind I choose another one for the answer, as Sunitha hits in 1 go?

Answer (score 1):

It would be

```
.*\(2016\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\)$
```

The $ symbol says its at the end